# How to linearize the nested parfor loop?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have two variables `i,j`, where `j` index start depends on `i` index.

```
n = 3;
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        % Feature matching
        matches = getMatches(input, allDescriptors{i}, allDescriptors{j});
        nf = size(matches, 2);
        numMatches(i,j) = nf;
    end   
end
```

I am trying to linearize it using the below code:

```
n = 3;
M = n;
N = n;
parfor i = 1:M*N
    % IND2SUB converts from a "linear" index into individual
    % subscripts
    [ii,jj] = ind2sub([M,N], i);
    
    if (ii~=jj)
        matches = getMatches(input, allDescriptors{ii}, allDescriptors{jj});
        nf = size(matches, 2);
        numMatches(i) = nf;
    end
end
```

But have some entries on the lower triangular part of the square matrix.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: It creates a matrix-like:  `0 4 7; 0 9 1; 0 9 5`. It should have the upper triangular elements except the diagonal.

Comment: Sorry, saw that wrong. Replace `if (ii~=jj)` with `if jj>ii`.

Comment: Now the matrix is `0 4 9; 0 5 5; 0 9 9`